# WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER gives error to server admin

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql, stored-procedures

In my vba application my users can change their roles in SQL server database by invoking the following Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_chgRole] 
    @usr nvarchar(7), @db nvarchar(8), @oldrole nvarchar(7), @newrole nvarchar(7)
    WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
    AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)          
                        
    --drop user from old role and add user to the new role 
    SET @sql = ' EXEC ' + @db + '.dbo.sp_droprolemember ''' + @oldrole + ''',''' + @usr + '''' +
                 EXEC ' + @db + '.dbo.sp_addrolemember ''' + @newrole + @usr + ''''

    EXEC (@sql)
END
```

This works well, when the users change their roles in their own database. The weird thing is, I want to use the same stored procedure with my sysadmin account, logged into my own database to change roles for users in their database. But when I try this, I get this error:

```
The server principal "<my account>" is not able to access the database "<users database" under the current security context.
```

Now, if I remove the WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER statement at the top of the stored procedure, I do not get an error and the roles are changed properly. But if I do that, my users get the error... This puzzles me. Why do I get the error when WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER is on, even though I am sysadmin and server admin? And how can I solve this without creating two stored procedures (one with and one without WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER)? I seems to me it should not be necessary to make two stored procedures...?

ps. I get the same error when I invoke the stored procedure from SSMS if the WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER is on.

Comment: This is expected. The default method is `EXECUTE AS CALLER`. You appear to have a cross database query here, and so *unless you have database chaining on, then the ownership chain is going to be lost. Why do you want `EXECUTE AS OWNER` when you have a cross database query?

Comment: Not to mention that `sp_droprolemember` and `sp_addrolemember` were deprecated in 2008/2012 (I can't recall which off the top of my head); you should be using `ALTER ROLE`.

Comment: And, finally, that is open to injecting, using a method that requires **no** injection. Though, when you move to `ALTER ROLE`, you would need to **safely** inject values.

Comment: Or maube your database has invalid owner? What returns `select suser_sname((select sid from sys.database_principals where name = N'dbo'))`? If `null`, then you have to change it, eg this way: `exec sp_changedbowner 'sa'`.

Comment: This honestly feels like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Why are you using a procedure, open to injection, to do this?

Comment: select suser_sname((select sid from sys.database_principals where name = N'dbo')) gives me my sysadmin account as the owner.  What do you mean by 'open to injection'? The program is running on a WIndows server, not a website. The stored procedures are invoked by VBA adodb connection.

Comment: But I think see what I should change now. The cross database query is not the best option...

Comment: *"The program is running on a WIndows server, not a website."* Injection isn't limited to websites. You are *blindly* injecting those parameters into the dynamic query. If you *must* use `sys.sp_droprolemember` then at least don't inject. `DECLARE @ProcName sysname = QUOTENAME(@db) + N'sys.sp_droprolemember'; EXEC @ProcName @OldRole, @Usr;` No injected needed. *This won't address the ownership issue.*

Comment: Thx guys for putting me on the right track. I went the wrong way with this. I changed it to ALTER ROLE and removed the cross database query element. It is working okay now. Also thank you for making the injection point clear to me. I gives me something to think about how I used to solve these problems